# Setting a variable in Angular in $watch block

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have the following:

```
        var s= '';
        $scope.$watch('foos', function(newValue, oldValue) {

            for(var i=0; i< newValue.length; i++){
                var name= newValue[i].barName;
                //console.log(name);
                s += name;
                s += "--";
            }
        });
        console.log(s);
```

'foos' is coming from a Restangular call, so it's a promise, so I had to wrap it in a $watch.
I want to set 's', and then use 's' outside of the $watch block, like where I have console.log().
The way things are now, 's' is always empty, how do I make it so that 's' is used after it gets set in the $watch block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `s` only after it's ready, here is one of the ways to do it:

```
 link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var s= '';
    $scope.$watch('foos', function(newValue, oldValue) {

        for(var i=0; i< newValue.length; i++){
            var name= newValue[i].barName;
            //console.log(name);
            s += name;
            s += "--";
        }
        if(s.length > 0)
            doStuffWithS($scope, $element, $compile, s);
    });


}

    function doStuffWithS($scope, $element, $compile, s) {
        // it goes here...

        $element[0].outerHTML("<div class='me'>" + s + "</div>";
        $compile($element.contents())($scope);

     }
```

The error i'm getting is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null

Comment: thx for the help, would u be able to answer this for me....i have this $watch in a directive, where the directive's job is to replace the element. i edited my my question, and i incorporated your answer, but something is not right, would u be able to make any suggestions?

Comment: i added if(s.length > 0) as a condition to the doStuffWithS(), and all seems to be ok...do u see any problems with doing that?

Comment: No problems. Checking `newValue`'s length seems a bit more intuitive, but `s` is fine as well. Glad you got it working.